# Excel VBA copy range as image with scaling

Tags: image, excel, vba

I have the following code that convert a range to image and save it to file. My problem is, I want to scale up the copied range to higher resolution/dpi to get bigger picture

```
Sub SaveRangeToImage(rng As Range, path As String)
    ''' Set Range you want to export to file
    Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = rng
    ''' Copy range as picture onto Clipboard
    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    ''' Create an empty chart with exact size of range copied
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .name = "img_img"
    .Activate
    End With
    ''' Paste into chart area, export to file, delete chart.
    ActiveChart.Paste
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("img_img").Chart.Export path
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("img_img").Delete
End Sub
```

I need to scale image up in order to get best text quality, if I resize it afterward, it gives me poor text visibility.

does anyone have an idea about this problem?

Comment: did you try to scale the chart before exporting it?

Comment: I think it will have the same effect as resizing image -> poor text quality

Comment: I tried it now and it does not have the same result in my case. I think it is better to give it a try. I just noticed reason already explained below why changing the size after pasting will work.

Comment: you were right @Dubison, I thought that the `CopyPicture` of `Range` object copies the picture in raster format. another day lived, another thing learned. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try changing the parameters:

```
rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlBitmap
```

- xlPrinter = might improve resolution for printing
- xlBitmap = will definitely increase the resolution as a bitmap

but @Dubison's suggestion will make the main difference:

- the chart in Excel is a "vector" image - increasing its size will not lower the resolution (bitmap images will have the same number of pixels at all sizes, vectors increase the number of pixels dynamically before being converted to a bitmap for printing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I mixed all possibilities of parameters (Appearance, Format) none increased the resolution with (xlPrinter, xlBitmap) gave me 1004 error. I am sure that excel charts are vector graphics but what I am trying to do here is copying a range (as raster picture i believe) to a chart object which gives the ability to save as picture, I will try resizing the chart object and give feedback later

Comment: I see, then the same idea (of vector format) can be applied to the range itself: increase the column width and row height for all affected cells, and also the font size; don't just zoom in, but actually increase the font size, so that when Excel converts the range to a bitmap (raster) it will be larger

Answer (score 0):

Increase the zoom of the active window to increase resolution.

Add in before the export: ActiveWindow.Zoom = 300
Then after the export add: ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

Comment: In my testing, this makes no difference.